# Value assignment to a (pseudo) function that is nowhere finite .

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Is there a method in mathematics literature which helps us to assign values (equivalent finite function) ( like analytic continuation but not analytic continuation) for (pseudo) functions that are nowhere finite ?

Example:

Can we assign a "finite function" for the given (pseudo) function ? :

$$f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{x/n²}$$

Comment: Your example of "nowhere finite function" simply is not a function (or better, it has empty domain). However, you could consider it as a formal series, without caring whether it converges or not.

Comment: @Crostul thanks for the comment